# Adding values from different tables

Tags: sql-server-2005

Friends, I have these tables:

```
Contestant Table:
Winner
Peter

Group Table:
Id Name Score Union
1 Bryan 3 77
2 Mary 1 20
3 Peter 5 77
4 Joseph 2 25
5 John 6 77
```

I want to give additional score of 5 to Peter on Group Table. So, I came up with this query.

```
UPDATE Group 
SET Score = Score+5
FROM Contestant, Group 
WHERE Contestant.Winner = Group.Name
```

Now, I want also to give additional score of 5 to the same Union as Peter which is 77.

How can I integrate it as one query to my existing query?

//UPDATE 1

I have similar question as above but using 3 tables:

```
1. Company (table)
CONAME
COPOINTS

2. Group_Member (table)
CONAME
NAME

3. Member (table)
NAME
MPOINTS
```

I would like to have a correct query as below answer with the following condition:

```
Update Member
Set MPOINTS=MPOINTS+5
Where Company.CONAME=Group_Member.CONAME
And
Group_Member.NAME=Member.NAME
```

Can you please correct above query?

Comment: You mean add 5 points to everyone that has the same union value as the winner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE Group 
SET Score = Score+5
WHERE [Union] = (
    SELECT [Union] 
    FROM Group, Contestant 
    WHERE Group.Name = Contestant.Winner)
```

Comment: i have added a question above because i don't want to start a new thread. can you please share your answer? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
update u set score = score + 5
from contestant c
inner join group g on g.name = c.winner
inner join group u on u.union = g.union
```

it's not clear, but if you want the winner to receive an additional 5 pts:

```
update u set score = (case
  when u.name = c.winner then score + 10
  else then score + 5 end)
from contestant c
inner join group g on g.name = c.winner
inner join group u on u.union = g.union
```